# KeyCodeCombination Control + LEFT or Ctrl + RIGHT key in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keycode

I am trying to build a video player. In that I want to seek media using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>LEFT</kbd> and <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> key.

I tried in two way:

```
KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+RIGHT").match(e);
```

and

```
KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.LEFT, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN).match(e);
```

Other key combinations worked but these did not.

Is there any way I can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [`SHORTCUT_DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#SHORTCUT_DOWN) rather than `CONTROL_DOWN` as the first one is platform independent.

> Returns whether or not the host platform common shortcut modifier is
>   down on this event. This common shortcut modifier is a modifier key
>   which is used commonly in shortcuts on the host platform. It is for
>   example control on Windows and meta (command key) on Mac.

Then you have several opportunities like:

```
node.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.LEFT, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN).match(e)) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

or

```
node.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT && e.isShortcutDown()) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I could use, but I do not want to. I specifically want to Use `Control+LEFT`. You can see on VLC Player & KMPlayer user can seek  media using these key combination. 
By the way, can you inform me, which one is shortcut key? I tried to use your provided key combination, but I could not implement that. I am using Windows 8.1 operating system.

Comment: Shortcut is the the control key on Windows. Could you post what you have at the moment? It would be much easier to help.

Comment: Here it is-
`if (keyCombinationControlRight.match(e) || new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.RIGHT, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN).match(e))    {
    System.err.println("CTRL+RIGHT");
    mediaPlayer.seek(new Duration(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toMillis() + longSeekTime.toMillis()));
   }
   else if (keyCombinationControlLeft.match(e)|| new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.LEFT, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN).match(e))
   {
    System.err.println("CTRL+LEFT");
    mediaPlayer.seek(new Duration(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toMillis() - longSeekTime.toMillis()));
   }
`

Comment: I ment to update the question. And also please, the whole code: for what do you attach the listener?

Comment: Sorry, its working. When you asked me to update the question, I was rearranging my code and then noticed that I was singularly checking for Left key only first and then on the next was checking key combination. That is why I was not getting my desired output. Now I just have put keycombination's line first and its working.

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy seeking! :)